# почему img и button не в линию

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}
nav.menu{
    display: flex;
    margin: 60px 150px 0 150px;
    width: 1140px;
    column-gap: 156px;
}
.link {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 42px;
}
.link a{
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    color: #4F5665;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.buttons{
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 11px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.logo{
    display: flex;
}
.perlink a{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    color: #0B132A;
}

.button{
    width:150px;
}
.button button{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #F53855;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height:45px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19px;
    color: #F53855;
    background: #fff;
    padding-bottom: 46px;
    margin-bottom:46px ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PRACTISE</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" rel="preconnect">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="menu">
    <div class="logo">
        <div class="image"><img src="images/Logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="link">
        <div class="text1"><a href="/">About</a></div>
        <div class="text2"><a href="/">Features</a></div>
        <div class="text3"><a href="/">Pricing</a></div>
        <div class="text4"><a href="/">Testimonials</a></div>
        <div class="text5"><a href="/">Help</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="perlink"><a href="/">Sign In</a></div>
        <div class="button">
            <button>Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: уберите все margin из меню....

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/poRzGEG - вот смотрите